# Is there a way to share a java project which use derby.jar files without sending the JDBC derby drivers?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc

I have a java project in intelliJ IDE( 2020.1) requires a login page and therefore needs access to a database.I've imported the libraries for derby in the project structure
C:\Program Files\Java\db-derby-10.14.2.0\lib\derby.jar on my PC.
However my teammates cannot run parts of the project which use the database(like the login) since they do not have the JDBC drivers installed as I do. Those working on the GUI cannot test for functionality even if they have the code(I have added the jdbc database I created to the repository).
To solve this I could guide them through the installation of the jdbc(by sending jerby.jar and other necessary files) but that would take a long time.
Is there a way for them to run the code and be able to use database functionality without installing the JDBC derby files on their individual PCs?

Comment: Almost all JDBC drivers are simply jar files that you can distribute like any other third-party library. If you use *any* third party library in a shared project you need a way to manage those dependencies. *Either* commit them to your repository in a `lib/` folder (simple, but has its own problems) or use a proper build system such as Maven/Gradle which handles downloading dependencies for you.

Comment: I second Joachim suggestion: use a build tool like Gradle or Maven to manage the dependencies.